# Localisation Issue in iOS 9

Tags: localization, ios9

My application support two languages English and Italian. It was working fine in iOS 8.4.1. But when i updated my device to iOS 9, my application stop working in Italian language and now i can only see English language. Can you please suggest what to do ?

I have tried one solution by change value to United state in key "Localization native development region" in the info.plist file.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion or Solution on what should be the problem with localisation in iOS 9?

Comment: Can anybody have any suggestions on this.